# Lipschitz continuity for a martingale (Durrett probability 4th edition 5.5.3)

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I want to show that for $f$ Lipschitz continuous, $X_n=\frac{(f((k+1)2^{-n})-f(k2^{-n}))}{2^{-n}}$ defines a martingale that converges almost surely in L^1. $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. I have the following:
$$E(X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n)=E\left(\frac{(f((k+1)2^{-(n+1)})-f(k2^{-(n+1)}))}{2^{-(n+1)}}|\mathcal{F}_n\right)\leq E\left(K\frac{(k+1)2^{-(n+1)}-k2^{-(n+1)}}{2^{-(n+1)}}|\mathcal{F}_n\right)\leq E(K|\mathcal{F}_n)$$
where $K$ is the Lipschitz constant. My issue is with finding what $K$ is, as well as a lower bound, since what I have will at best show that this is a supermartingale. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Fairly sure that the Lipschitz continuity is just to show the almost sure convergence in $L^1$. We can keep $K$ general I would have thought.

(Once we have shown it is a martingale)
You can get $L^1$ convergence using Doob's second martingale convergence theorem. This is because $X_{n}$ is uniformly integrable. 

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems)

To see this: note that $|X_n| \leq K$, so for $C$ large enough, no $X_n(\omega) \geq C$. I.e.  $\int_{X_n > C}|X_n(\omega)|dP = 0$

Comment: We may need to know more about $f$ to prove it is a martingale.

Comment: $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the only other detail about $f$ (forgot to add it up there, sorry)

Comment: f is deterministic then?

Comment: the problem statement doesn't say... but let's suppose it is

Comment: then $X_n$ is non random!!

Comment: The definition of $X_n$ relayed by the OP is not complete: $X_n$ is to take the value $[f((k+1)2^{-n})-f(k2^{-n})]\cdot 2^n$ on the interval $I_{n,k}:=[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.